# How can I change the color of the titled border in my GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I've already looked at other similar posts on how to do this, but I don't understand any of them. Most of them use this object called "TitledBorder", but I simply use the method ".setBorder()". I want to change the colour of the border and the colour of the titles as well. Please help me out, and thank you!

```
private void layoutView()
{

//The JPanel that holds the JTextField. This is the first
//JPanel that I want to change the color of the titled border
JPanel question = new JPanel();
question.add(this.question);
question.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Ask a question"));

//The JPanel that holds the JLabel. 
//This is the second JPanel that I want to change the colour of.
JPanel questionAnswerPanel = new JPanel();
questionAnswerPanel.add (this.questionAnswer);
questionAnswerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Prediction"));

//The JPanel that holds the question JPanel so it can be centered
JPanel center = new JPanel();
center.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
center.add(question, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//The complete layout
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.add(questionAnswerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
question.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Ask a question"));
```

What don't you understand about that statement? Did you read the API?

The `BorderFactory` returns an instance of the `TitledBorder` class, so you assign it to a variable and then you can invoke any method from the TitledBorder class.

```
//question.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Ask a question"));
TitledBorder border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Ask a question");
border.setTitleColor( Color.RED );
question.setBorder( border );
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the actual API, the only thing that I relied on was the information my teacher gave me. I will try that now, and let you know if it works, thank you.

Comment: I tried that, and it works, thank you for that. But, is there anyway I can change the color of the border itself?

Comment: @Anonymous *I didn't read the actual API* - well that is the first thing you need to do as a programmer is learn to read the API. *is there anyway I can change the color of the border itself?* - it you don't see a method in the API that supports that then it can't be done without custom coding. In this case you would need to implement your own custom Border class and implement the custom painting logic yourself. You can always download the JDK source and try to modify the existing TitledBorder painting code.